# Xamarin.MacOS SignalR: Cannot resolve the reference System.Readonly Memory System.Byte Microsoft.Aspnetcore.SignalR.Protocol.Handshakeprotocol

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms, signalr

I am working with both AutoFac and SignalR, and everything works great in debug mode for Xamarin.Forms.MacOS.

Since I use autofac, I need to set `Link Framework SDKs only`, if not, I get a runtime exception in releasemode.

Now my current issue is that i have a compilation issue when setting it to `Link Framework SDKs only`. The followingn error i get looks like this:

`Cannot resolve the reference system.readonly memory <system.byte> microsoft.aspnetcore.signalR.protocol.handshakeprotocol`

[image]

If i set my Linker to `Link all`, then I can successfully launch the app, but as stated above, I get a Runtime exception because of an issue with Autofac.

Any idea on how i can solve this?

Comment: Use the `[Preserve]` attribute or create an XML file that would exclude namespaces/classes from being stripped out by linker. More [info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos)

Comment: A dirty solution also is to make a reference of the class. You can use the `discard` trick.

Comment: so i added `--linkskip=Autofac` and app compiles and i get parts of the mainscreen. not sure if there is some other issue now. it is not showing all the design

Comment: same issue on debug mode. adding that line seems to cause issues when rendering the forntpage

Comment: You have to be specific with your problem otherwise we can't help you.